# jQuery Give each li a certain background color in a dynamic type pattern

Tags: jquery, css

I need some code to allow li's to get a certain background color as they progress.

For exmaple there are 5 colors

Blue
Red
Green
Yellow
Orange

I need it so the li will follow this certain pattern and when there is more than 5 li's the 6th will be blue again and continue through the sequence.

So it will become:
Blue
Red
Green
Yellow
Orange
Blue
Red
etc..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're asking for code, and haven't tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 3):

using css - [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) - Note: IE < 9 not supported

```
li:nth-child(5n + 1) {
    color: blue;
}
li:nth-child(5n + 2) {
    color: red;
}
li:nth-child(5n + 3) {
    color: green;
}
li:nth-child(5n + 4) {
    color: yellow;
}
li:nth-child(5n) {
    color: orange;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Xh8gq/)

using jQuery [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value)

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', ...]
$('li').css('color', function(idx){
    return colors[idx % colors.length]
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yJZNA/)

Comment: +1. Nice use of jQuery's callback-to-set-property thing, about which I'm kicking myself for forgetting in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nth-child css selector for this purpose.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Look at example 2

> Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is
>   a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.
>
> Here, we specify a background color for all p elements whose index is
>   a multiple of 3:

```
p:nth-child(3n+0)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't really use w3 schools as an example - http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @HasanAlaca That's a common misapprehension - http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: @Pete is the content above wrong though? This isn't some political forum for views about companies and their practices rather about finding correct answers to questions!

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I never commented on your answer, just on the site and it isn't political - it's just pointing out a lot of their content is wrong, but go ahead continue using it if you like

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to do it in your style sheet for some reason (and putting as much effort into my explanation as you put into your question):

```
var colors = ['blue','red','green','yellow','orange'];
$("li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[i%colors.length]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
li:nth-of-type(5n+1){background-color:blue;}
li:nth-of-type(5n+2){background-color:red;}
li:nth-of-type(5n+3){background-color:green;}
li:nth-of-type(5n+4){background-color:yellow;}
li:nth-of-type(5n+5){background-color:orange;}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/HDGyk/)